# Как сделать перемещаемые элементы

Tags: android

Увидел одну очень интересную настройку в приложении, пытался искать в интернете, но не знаю как правильно называется данная штучка, подскажите новичку), желательно не только название а ещё и простой пример как её реализовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете посмотреть [этот проект на гитхабе](https://github.com/EasonHolmes/RecyclerView_Swipe_Move).

Answer (score 2):

В мире взаимодействия с сенсорными экранами есть несколько понятий, некоторые из них Touch, DoubleTouch, Swipe, Drag and Drop. Вас интересует Drag-and-drop (D&D, DnD, DND, в переводе с английского означает буквально тащи-и-бросай; Бери-и-Брось).

Реализовать данный функционал можно различными способами, от современного решения с ItemTouchHelper, до более простых решений в виде сторонних библиотек. Лично я имею опыт использования этой библиотеки https://github.com/ernestoyaquello/DragDropSwipeRecyclerview у неё понятная документация, а так же она позволит помимо перемещения объектов, реализовать удаление по свайпу. Прошу заметить, что вам необходимо быть знакомым с реализацией отображения списка элементов через RecyclerView.

Если кратко для реализации списка с использованием RecyclerView вам понадобится Активити или Фрагмент содержащий в своей разметке `<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/`> или `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/>` (Если вы решили использовать мою рекомендацию по библиотеке используйте `<com.ernestoyaquello.dragdropswiperecyclerview.DragDropSwipeRecyclerView/>`)

В коде активити или фрагмента задайте лаяут менеджер `recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)`. А также присвойте адаптер `recyclerView.adapter = adapter`, это должен быть созданный вами наследник `RecyclerView.Adapter<Ваш адаптер.Holder>()` или в случаи реализации через библиотеку `DragDropSwipeAdapter<Ваша сущность, Ваш адаптер.Holder>(список ваших сущностей)`.

Задача адаптера поместить данные в вашу сущность и затем recyclerView возьмет на себя обязанности по оптимизированной отрисовке вашего списка. Как вы могли заметить адаптер содержит в себе Holder, это наследник `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)` который содержит в себе вашу view элемента списка. Другими словами адаптер заполнит view данными из вашей сущности и будет хитрым образом отрисовывать их. Возможности безграничны, у вас наверняка будут возникать вопросы, я хотел направить вас на слова которые погут вам в дальнейших поисках. Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Эта штука называется ItemTouchHelper.

Реализуется примерно так:

```
public class RecyclerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter { 

    // ... 

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) { 
        mItems.remove(position);
         notifyItemRemoved(position); 
     } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) { 
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) { 
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) { 
              BbCollections.swap(mItems, i, i + 1); 
            } 
        } else { 
             for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) { 
                 Collections.swap(mItems, i, i - 1); 
             }
         } 
         notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition); 
         return true; 
     }
```

[Здесь](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/427681/) можно почитать больше.
Ещё можно заглянуть в [документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper)